# Pull content render in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a requirement where i need to pull information from some other non sharepoint site into sharepoint page layout.I have that site information in XML also.Does anyone is having idea how to acheive this in sharepoint .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the xml as a datasource in SharePoint Designer and then use it with the Data View Web Part, that uses Xsl to style the data, which you can then customize fully your self, more info [here](http://www.lcbridge.nl/vision/2009/dvwp.htm).